# Combining all data in a data frame per column and groups in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have this dataset, which is composed by 3 columns and 5 observations:

```
sex <- c("M", "M", "F", "F", "F")
var1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
var2 <- c(6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

data <- data.frame(sex, var1, var2)
print(data)

   sex var1 var2
1   M   1   6
2   M   2   7
3   F   3   8
4   F   4   9
5   F   5   10
```

I would like to divide each male (`M`) by each female (`F`) in every column.

In this example, which is very simple, I would like to get for `var1` a vector of `1/3`, `1/4`, `1/5`, `2/3`, `2/4` and `2/5`.

For `var2`, the vector would be `6/8`, `6/9`, `6/10`, `7/8`, `7/9` and `7/10`.

Finally, I would have 2 vectors, each for every variable.

How can I automate this considering I have much more columns and rows?

Comment: Do you want to expand the datasset.  Can you sshow the expected output

Comment: It would be like a dataframe with two columns (`var1` and `var2`). Each one containing the indexes in every vector mentioned before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option would be to get the index of elements in 'sex' that are "M", loop,  subset the 'var' columns where the sex is "F" and divide the the vars corresponding to "M" and `rbind`

```
out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(which(data$sex == "M"), function(i) {
     d1 <- data[data$sex == "F", -1]
     data[i, -1][rep(1, nrow(d1)),]/d1 }))
row.names(out) <- NULL
out
#       var1      var2
#1 0.3333333 0.7500000
#2 0.2500000 0.6666667
#3 0.2000000 0.6000000
#4 0.6666667 0.8750000
#5 0.5000000 0.7777778
#6 0.4000000 0.7000000
```

---

Another option is `outer`

```
i1 <- which(data$sex == "M")
i2 <- setdiff(seq_len(nrow(data)), i1)
sapply(2:ncol(data), function(u) 
        outer(i1, i2, FUN  = function(i, j) data[i, u]/data[j, u]))
#      [,1]      [,2]
#[1,] 0.3333333 0.7500000
#[2,] 0.6666667 0.8750000
#[3,] 0.2500000 0.6666667
#[4,] 0.5000000 0.7777778
#[5,] 0.2000000 0.6000000
#[6,] 0.4000000 0.7000000
```

Comment: I am getting this error `Error in dat[i, -1] : incorrect number of dimensions`

Comment: @antecessor  I used your data only.  Couldn't reproduce the error

Comment: @antecessor  I mistyped `data` as `dat`.  Can you check now

Comment: don't know what's wrong with this, as I am emplying my example and your code. I am getting this error now: `Error in do.call(rbind, lapply(which(data$sex == "M"), function(i) { : 
  'what' must be a function or character string`

Comment: @antecessor  I double checked, it is sstill giving the output without any error

Comment: Got it. I had an object named `rbind` which was creating troubles. It worked

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to use the base R `merge` function, in cross join mode:

```
cross <- merge(data[sex=="M",], data[sex=="F",], by=NULL)
df <- data.frame(var1=cross$var1.x/cross$var1.y, var2=cross$var2.x/cross$var2.y)
df

       var1      var2
1 0.3333333 0.7500000
2 0.6666667 0.8750000
3 0.2500000 0.6666667
4 0.5000000 0.7777778
5 0.2000000 0.6000000
6 0.4000000 0.7000000
```

I didn't bother to sort the data frame above, or bring in any of the original variables, but it would not be too difficult to do that.